# Kohana 404 error when go to some edit pages

Tags: url, routes, http-status-code-404, kohana

I have a problem with website coded in Kohana framework. 
I'm not author of it, but I needed to change hosting.

I moved it from other site to the new and all is ok, but when I go to some pages, wchich edit some objects on my site (admin panel -> objects (ex. hotels, tours etc.) and I choose someone object and want to edit that, then page goes from url `sitename.xyz/admin,hotels,edit,<id>` to `sitename.xyz/404error`

`sitename.xyz/admin,hotels,list` and `sitename.xyz/admin,hotels,add` works properly.

I have no idea what code can I attach. I'm adding .htacces code, but if something is needed - please notice it me, I will edit the post. My page is online, so I can give link if someone need.

.htacces code:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

###### Add trailing slash (optional) ######
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)public_html/index.php/(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|media)
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What does the Kohana error log say?

Comment: For that error say nothing (loging is on).

Comment: check routes set in bootstrap or on moduel, most users use this URL structure. doamin/controller/action/ID in your case it looks like its a Route setting. search your code for Route::set and check its setting.